# How to loop the getline function in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, while-loop, cin, getline

Can anyone explain to me why my **getline()** statement from my code is not looping as I could expect, I want the code inside the **while** loop to execute forever but then my code only loops the code but skips the **getline()** function. I'll provide the screenshot...my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int age;

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Enter your age: ";
        cin >> age;

        cout << "Age: " << age << "\tName: " << name << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

the output loops only the **cin** function and no solution I have found so far that put things clear. My code runs like:
[image: The Image of my code after running it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while(true)
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Enter your age: ";
        cin >> age;

        cout << "Age: " << age << "\tName: " << name << "\n\n";
        cin.get(); //<-- Add this line
    }
```

Edit:
std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); is a safer solution since if you use cin.get(); and type "19 " or other combinations for age, the problem will repeat itself.

Thanks to @scohe001

Final:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int age;
    string name;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Enter your age: ";
        cin >> age;

        cout << "Age: " << age << "\tName: " << name << "\n\n";
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Thanks to @user4581301

Comment: Careful, this'll work only if they've entered "{age}[newline]", not "{age}[space][newline]" or any other combination.

Comment: Never tried that before since the console applications were mostly homeworks, great catch. How to prevent that?

Comment: The line solved my problem, I'll need to look into the **cin.get()** function to understand what happened.

Comment: But as @scohe001 mentioned, if you try to type "19 " with a space and press enter the problem will repeat itself. A safer solution is changing that line to std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

Comment: @Supreme `get()` simply reads one character from the stream (and it is discarded, since there return value is not saved into any variable). For an actual detailed answer, see the duplicate question.

Comment: I like the limitation on the maximum number of characters ignored. The idiomatic version is `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`, but typically if you're chucking more than a few hundred characters to find the end of the line, something has gone very very wrong and you should probably stop and find out what.